# How to store dictionary entries in a loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I've been trying to get a dictionary with tuple of strings a key of an integer out of a CSV file but am having trouble.

This is the code I have tried:

```
fullcsv = [['Brand', 'Swap', 'Candy1', 'Candy2', 'Capacity'],
           ['Willywonker', 'Yes', 'bubblegum', 'mints', '7'],
           ['Mars-CO', 'Yes', 'chocolate', 'bubblegum', '1'],
           ['Nestle', 'Yes', 'bears', 'bubblegum', '2'],
           ['Uncle Jims', 'Yes', 'chocolate', 'bears', '5']]

def findE(fullcsv):
    i = 0
    a = {}
    while i < len(fullcsv)-1:
        i = i + 1
        a[i] = ({(fullcsv[i][2],fullcsv[i][3]): int(fullcsv[i][4])})
    return a
```

This is the output for this chunk of code:

```
{1: {('bubblegum', 'mints'): 7},
 2: {('chocolate', 'bubblegum'): 1},
 3: {('bears', 'bubblegum'): 2},
 4: {('chocolate', 'bears'): 5}}
```

But the output I'm looking for is more like this:

```
{('bubblegum', 'mints'): 7,
 ('chocolate', 'bubblegum'): 1,
 ('bears', 'bubblegum'): 2,
 ('chocolate', 'bears'): 5}
```

so that the tuples aren't numbered and also aren't in their own `{}`, but just in parentheses `()`.

Comment: It's easier to iterate through the csv using `for row in fullcsv:[1:]`, rather than using the `i` index. The code will look less complicated.

Comment: If you can try then change this line `a[i] = ({(fullcsv[i][2],fullcsv[i][3]): int(fullcsv[i][4])})` to `a[(fullcsv[i][2],fullcsv[i][3])]=int(fullcsv[i][4]` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within the function you need to set the key value pair of the dictionary like so

```
a[(fullcsv[i][2],fullcsv[i][3])] = int(fullcsv[i][4])
```

so that the full function is

```
def findE(fullcsv):
    i = 0
    a ={}
    while i < len(fullcsv)-1:
        i = i + 1
        a[(fullcsv[i][2],fullcsv[i][3])] = int(fullcsv[i][4])
            
    return a
```

the general syntax is

```
dictionary[new_key] = new_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different way if you want.

```
def findE(fullcsv):
    new_dict = {}
    for entry in fullcsv[1:]:
        new_dict[(entry[2],entry[3])] = entry[-1]
    return new_dict
```

Comment: Nice. You could reduce this to: `return {(e[2], e[3]): int(e[-1]) for e in fullcsv[1:]}`.